# Using getline to read data from a file in C++

Tags: c++, file, input

I want to read from a file two things, the full name (first name and last name)
and age. After that I want to store them in an array then print the data.
However, when I try to reading the first record is read find, but the other two are not.
Please tell me what am I missing.
Thank you.

The content of the file is:

```
sampleFirst1 sampleLast1
30
sampleFirst2 sampleLast2
25
sampleFirst3 sampleLast3
40
```

The Output is:

```
Name:  sampleFirst1 Age: 30
Name:  Age: 30
Name:  Age: 30
```

Here's my Code:

```
#include "Person.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream inputFile("data.txt", ios::in);
    string full_name;
    int age = 0;

    int i = 0;
    Person personArray[3];
    while (i < 3)
    {
        getline(inputFile, full_name);
        personArray[i].set_name(full_name);
        inputFile >> age;
        personArray[i].set_age(age);
        ++i;
    }
    inputFile.close();
    printData(personArray, 3);
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: You increment i for every line, not for every person.

Comment: 'getline(inputFile, full_name);' are you trying to read a line of text into an int ? How does that even compile ?

Comment: Sorry that wasn't the point I just corrected the type.

Comment: sdotdi, what do you mean? Can you clarify more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not mix `getline` and the `>>` operator in that way. Prefer a simpler code like this one :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <array>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct Person {
  std::string name;
  int age;

  void set_name(std::string const& i_name) { name = i_name; }
  void set_age(int i_age) { age = i_age; }
};                                                                                                                                                                                        

int main()
{
  ifstream inputFile("data.txt", ios::in);
  std::string first;
  std::string last;
  int age = 0;

  int i = 0;
  std::array<Person,3> personArray;
  while (i < personArray.size())                                                                                                                                                                                                                  {
    inputFile >> first >> last >> age;
    personArray[i].set_name(first + " " + last);
    personArray[i].set_age(age);
    ++i;
  }
  inputFile.close();

  for(Person const& person : personArray) {
    std::cout << "Name: " << person.name << " Age: " << person.age << "\n";
  }
  std::cout << std::flush;

  return 0;
}
```

Or use only `getline` and a `istringstream` to pase the age if you dont want to pay the string concatenation extra cost for the full name.

A lot could be said of the parsing method but that is not the point here.

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I wanted. Thank you.